# How to filter inconsistent records in sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, group-by, database-optimization

Say I have SQLite table with the following records:

| recID | productID | productName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Product A |
| 2 | 2 | Product B |
| 3 | 2 | Product C |
| 4 | 3 | Product D |
| 5 | 3 | Product D |

recID = primary key, auto increment.

If I run:

```
SELECT productID, productName 
FROM table 
GROUP BY productID, productName
```

Result is:

| productID | productName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Product A |
| 2 | Product B |
| 2 | Product C |
| 3 | Product D |

As you can see, productID 2 has inconsistent productName: `Product B and Product C`. How do I run query just to detect the inconsistent ones? Eg I want the result to be:

| productID | productName |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Product B |
| 2 | Product C |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` to get a `productID` with more than 1 `productName`s:

```
SELECT t1.productID, t1.productName 
FROM tablename t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM tablename t2
  WHERE t2.productID = t1.productID AND t2.productName <> t1.productName 
);
```

Or, for a small dataset use aggregation in a subquery which counts the distinct number of `productName`s of each `productID`, with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT productID, productName 
FROM tablename
WHERE productID IN (
  SELECT productID
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY productID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT productName) > 1
);
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked but super slow. It took 11.262 s in a table with just 15000 rows using nvme ssd gen 4 which is supposedly to be really fast. I think loading with SELECT * and filtering in app is much faster. My goal is to have faster result than processing via app

Comment: @AlbertTobing a condition like `t2.productID = t1.productID AND t2.productName <> t1.productName` needs a composite index for  (productID, productName) in that order.

Comment: Your second suggestion performed much much faster ! 0.004s. This is more like it although I am not sure if this is good enough for table with 15000 rows

Comment: @AlbertTobing probably the subquery returns a small dataset. This is the only case that IN would be preferred over EXISTS.

Comment: A little bit update. The query doesn't seem to work when I introduce more inconsistency. For example if I add 4 more records to table above: [ Product ID 2 --> Product E ]. [ Product ID 2 --> Product E ]. [ Product ID 2 --> Product F ]. [ Product ID 2 --> Product F ]

Comment: @AlbertTobing what problem? Both queries return all the rows for product id = 2: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0232f5ad4b2434df021a7825b23a576f

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d133d3d9159c3ec465ee75a96c63b86f

There prodID 1 is consistent while 2 and 3 are not. your query exclude prodID 1 which is correct but repeat the rest many times. the old query does not repeat duplicate but also include prodID 1 (the only consistent one)

Comment: basically the result i am expecting is the result from the old query minus the consistent one (prodID 1). from the above fiddle, the correct result should be 6 rows. 2 x prodID 2 + 4 x prodID 3

Comment: @AlbertTobing if you want distinct rows simply add DISTINCT after SELECT: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=61fe6bd7cc0f6c847e1ce83f7d7d6d80